# Importing scope of a whole mother class

Tags: c++, scope, using

In my specific problem, there's an inheritance of dependent class, namely:

```
template<typename type>
struct Base{
    int a;
}
template<typename type>
struct Derived: Base<type>{
    void func(int b){
        Base<type>::a = b
    }
}
```

In this example, I have to use `Base<type>::a` to access the variable because `Base<type>` is dependent on the template parameter `type`. But this is quite annoying that everytime we have to add a prefix `Base<type>::`.

Another workaround would be like:

```
template<typename type>
struct Derived: Base<type>{
    using Base<type>::a;
    void func(int b){
        a = b
    }
}
```

However, it is still annoying because we have to repeat every data member that is used. Is there a way to import the whole scope of the mother class into its derived class?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this` to avoid specifying the full base class scope

```
void func(int b){
    this->a = b;
}
```

This would be less to type, and easier to handle in case of future renamings and refactorings.

See a working [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fea36d3d57ac2809).

---

The shortest prefix you can achieve would be three letters:

```
template<typename type>
struct Derived: Base<type>{
    using B = Base<type>;
    void func(int b){
        B::a = b;
    }
};
```

Comment: Oh, that actually works.
But I'm still curious if importing the scope explicitly for once is possible. After all adding `this->` as prefix each time can as well be annoying.

Comment: @TaylorHuang No, that's not possible. The compiler need to see a way to access the base class members.

Comment: I don't understand. If it is possible to simply add a prefix `using Base<type>::a`
whay can't we have something to "add all" or simply postpone the check until the template is about to be instantiated?

Comment: @TaylorHuang Well, c++ doesn't support that feature.

Comment: One important difference between the options: when calling a virtual function of the base class, `this->func(`...`)` will call the final overrider as normal, but `Base<type>::func(`...`)` or `B::func(`...`)` will call exactly the named function, ignoring overrides.